# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in a Flask application. Works in local but not in server

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, plotly-dash, wsgi

In **local** my Flask application works fine, and when I use `/editing_buddy` it redirects me correctly.
The thing is, when I upload it to the **server**, it always gives me `404 Error`.

If I try to use `@app.route` decorator, I get a `TOO MANY REDIRECTS error`.
My server is hosted by Wikimedia in funpedia.toolforge.org if that helps. It's a webservice with kubernetes backend.

My code is like this:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True, debug=True)


# Load configuration from YAML file
__dir__ = os.path.dirname(__file__)
app.config.update(
    yaml.safe_load(open(os.path.join(__dir__, 'config.yaml'))))

@app.route('/')
def index():

    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))

@app.route('/editing_buddy')
def buddy():

    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('buddy'))

@app.errorhandler(404)
def handling_page_not_found(e):
    return "<h1>404</h1><p>The resource could not be found.</p>", 404
```

The apps for the "/" and "/editing_buddy" are Dash applications with the same url_base_pathname:

**Buddy**

```
buddy_app = Dash(__name__, server=application, url_base_pathname="/editing_buddy/",
                             external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
buddy_app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True
```

**Home**

```
 home_app = Dash(__name__, server=application, url_base_pathname="/", 
                           external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
 home_app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True



from view.home import *
from view.editing_buddy_app import *
```

Locally, I start the server by running `wsgi.py`. Which contains the code:

```
from app import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

In the server I simply run `webservice restart`, but I have a .ini file called `app.ini` with content:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi
callable = application
```

And my folder structure is
[image: Folder Structure]

**PS**: I've also tried hardcoding the redirects like `flask.redirect("/editing_buddy/")`. Even i've tried to hardcode the URL like `flask.redirect("funpedia.toolforge.org/editing_buddy/")` and either doesn't find it or Too many redirects.

**You can see my repo [HERE](https://github.com/Destokado/funpedia)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works, why? I don't have any clue. I did the next:

1. I eliminated the `app.ini` from the directory of the `app.py` and put it on the root directory.
2. In `home.py`, I renamed `from app import app as application` to just `from app import app`.
3. Eliminated the unnecessary `@app.route` for the dash apps, they are not needed because you already have the `url_base_pathname`.

After doing some testing, I found that the **solution is the step 2.** By using `from app import app` in the `home.py` script.

**HOWEVER**, in the `editing_buddy_app.py`, I have it with `from app import app as application` **AND IT WORKS**

Definitely, I'm missing something here, but I'm unable to guess what.

Answer (score 2):

You are literally redirecting in your methods to the exact same method you're doing the redirect from. By doing so you are creating an endless loop, and TBH this should even throw errors locally.

I advise you to give this [medium.com article](https://medium.com/@olegkomarov_77860/how-to-embed-a-dash-app-into-an-existing-flask-app-ea05d7a2210b) a good read to make sure you set up both Dash and Flask correctly, using the [Application Factory Pattern.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/appfactories/)

===================================================

EDIT:

This is a copy/paste from the article I linked, you can see that when the Flask app gets instantiated, it also creates the Dash apps, using the Flask app as the server...

**dashboard.py**

```py
def create_app():
    server = Flask(__name__)
    server.config.from_object(BaseConfig)

    register_dashapps(server)
# snipped some here

    return server


def register_dashapps(app):
    from app.dashapp1.layout import layout
    from app.dashapp1.callbacks import register_callbacks

    # Meta tags for viewport responsiveness
    meta_viewport = {"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"}

    dashapp1 = dash.Dash(__name__,
                         server=app,
                         url_base_pathname='/dashboard/',
                         assets_folder=get_root_path(__name__) + '/dashboard/assets/',
                         meta_tags=[meta_viewport])

    with app.app_context():
        dashapp1.title = 'Dashapp 1'
        dashapp1.layout = layout
        register_callbacks(dashapp1)

    _protect_dashviews(dashapp1)
```

===================================================

EDIT2:

Thanks for adding the repo, this helped in figuring out what is going on, and I think I have a grasp of what you want to do based on the rest of the code. I'm guessing you want to put authentication logic in your app so not everyone can just access your handlers for the respective Dash apps.

Thing is, you are running into one of the exact same issues described in the [first article](https://medium.com/@olegkomarov_77860/how-to-embed-a-dash-app-into-an-existing-flask-app-ea05d7a2210b) I linked, which is the authentication.

You *will* need to refactor your code if you want to use authentication, similar to what is discussed in the aforementioned article.

While researching this question I did come across an article which might interest you, as it discusses how to implement authentication. It's also a simpler article, and it basically allows you to apply Flask stuff to Dash apps. Find it [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-setup-user-authentication-for-dash-apps-using-python-and-flask-6c2e430cdb51)...

Comment: Yes, I know, but somehow in another server I've been working on, it runs perfectly fine. The thing is, why does it work locally but not in the server? If I use the @app.route it also gives me the too many redirects, but if I don't use it, It finds the correct app. That's what's weird from me.

Comment: Do you import  the actual Dash apps? (as the import section is missing). Second, how do you run locally (*env* variables matter here)? Third, what's the contents of `wsgi.py`?

Comment: Yes, I import the dash apps via
`from view.home import *`
I run locally by running the wsgi.py.

THe contents of wsgi.py are
`from app import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()`

Comment: I just edited the post and added what you requested. Moreover, I linked my REPO below if you need to see anything I'm missing. About the code you pasted, It builds everything so modularly that's (in my opinion) making things way more complicated than they should be, as I'm only planning to have 4 dash apps (home, editing buddy, and 2 more)

Comment: Thanks for adding the repo gimme some time to digest it. **First thing to note, you have client secret and client key files in your public repo. Consider these compromised. I did not go through your whole repo yet, so I'm not sure where they are used, but as stated, consider these compromised and revoke them if needed...**

Comment: Oh thank you so much, you're totally right. Fortunately those were revoked so were never useful, but very important to note! 
**The branch test2 works** completely fine when put on the **server**, but can't find where are the differences that make it work.